# Android Create Pdf other than itext

Tags: java, android, itext

I was successful exporting content to pdf using itext but then their commercial package is much than what i thought. is there any other way free/paid way of exporting content to pdf?

Comment: Open Office can export to PDF, so I would think that there is a way to export to a PDF in the Open Office API.

Answer (score -1):

Flying Saucer takes XML or XHTML and applies CSS 2.1-compliant stylesheets to it, in order to render to PDF (via iText), images, and on-screen using Swing or SWT. The library implements (basically) the entirety of CSS 2.1 and aims to be fully compliant with the W3C specification; it includes a small handful of CSS 3 features.

http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Comment: Hi i dont want to use itext. Is there any other way to generate pdf? i am developing a commercial app. IText's library are way too expensive!!!

Comment: Also, as far as I know, Flyingsaucer uses classes not available for Android (javax.*), so it's not suited for Android.